# Eclipse error while building workspace

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, macos

I am facing this issue everytime i start eclipse.

[image]

This is messing up the `xml` layouts. How do i reslove this ?

Comment: Maybe recreate workspace settings can help You.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily fix this

1) close your eclipse

2) go to your workspace folder

3) and delete .metadata folder

4) open your eclispse again

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to *Android SDK*. Check for SDK updates and install it. Reopen Eclipse and every thing should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but have to re-import all the project from the workspace, as we are deleting the metadata.